# Calculate maximum value by day of the year over certain period

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following **data frame**:

```
my_index = ['2005-03-20', '2008-03-20', '2014-03-20', '2007-08-15', '2012-08-15', '2007-12-31', '2011-12-31', '2013-12-31', '2014-12-31']
df = pd.DataFrame([42, 51, 36, 217, 228, -56, -50, -66, -32], index = my_index, columns = ['Temperature'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Which looks like this:

```
            Temperature
2005-03-20           42
2008-03-20           51
2014-03-20           36
2007-08-15          217
2012-08-15          228
2007-12-31          -56
2011-12-31          -50
2013-12-31          -66
2014-12-31          -32
```

What I want is to **calculate the maximum value by day of the year over the period 2005-2014**. The **desired output** would be this one:

```
       Temperature
03-20           51
08-15          228
12-31          -32
```

Any idea? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` by `Series` created by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
print (df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d')).max())
       Temperature
03-20           51
08-15          228
12-31          -32
```

For filtering use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` created by [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), because [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) return `numpy array` too:

```
mask = np.in1d(df.index.year, np.arange(2005, 2015))
print (df[mask].groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d')).max())
       Temperature
03-20           51
08-15          228
12-31          -32
```

Comment: Great! Thank you